# How to give a name/value attribute to a select field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have these 2 functions:

```
  handleHomeInput = (e) => {
    let stateCopy = { ...this.state };
    stateCopy.home.name = e.target.innerText;
    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };

  handleAwayInput = (e) => {
    let stateCopy = { ...this.state };
    stateCopy.away.name = e.target.innerText;
    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };
```

clearly very similar and could be refactored into 1 method.

these methods both take the innerText of a dropdown. If they were normal inputs I could take the name or value attribute from `e.target.value` and then could refactor line 3. however this is not possible as dropdowns don't seem to have that value param on them.

I am using semantic-ui by the way. any ideas how I could refactor these?

my state just looks like this:

```
state = {
    home: {
      name: '',
      goals: 0
    },
    away: {
      name: '',
      goals: 0
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your inputs:

```
<input name="home" onChange={this.handleInput} ... />
<input name="away" onChange={this.handleInput} ... />
```

Then:

```
handleInput = (e) => {
   const { name, innerText } = e.target
   const prevState = this.state[name]
   this.setState({ [name]: {...prevState, name: innerText } })
}
```

Or, (to answer your comments below) to add a custom field name:

```
handleInput = (name) => (e) => {
   const { innerText } = e.target
   const prevState = this.state[name]
   this.setState({ [name]: {...prevState, name: innerText } })
}
```

then you can use it as:

```
<input onChange={this.handleInput('home')} ... />
<input onChange={this.handleInput('away')} ... />
```

or, if you want to make it even more generic:

```
handleInput = (name) => (value) => {
   const prevState = this.state[name]
   this.setState({ [name]: {...prevState, name: value } })
}
```

then use it as:

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleInput('home')(e.target.innerText)} ... />
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleInput('away')(e.target.innerText)} ... />
```

Comment: I've done exactly this and it wont work because it's a drop down. i just get undefined for `e.target.name`. I know this works for inputs but it wont work on semantic ui dropdowns....

Comment: Ok, I just updated my answer so you can pass a name if the component doesn't provide one.

Comment: You've got options now :) pick what suits you best

Comment: I don't know at what point you will acknowledge it's not an input but a semantic-ui dropdown - see https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-search-selection-two - onChange will pass a second arg with the relevant values you may need.

Comment: Mate, I just used input as an example, you can pass it to whatever component you like.

Comment: not when it's a custom component - then the ref will only be as good as getting you the instance of the Dropdown but it may not have a `.value` getter

Comment: I'm only taking in account that the functions described in the question work, so if they work, then any of the bottom two solutions would work

Comment: Plus it doesn't have to be a "plug-and-play option", the question was about how to refactor those two functions to update that piece of state.

Comment: @ArberSylejmani the problem is I cant pass in home because my state is an object...I need to pass in (home.name) or (home.goals) but this wont work...

Comment: the question clearly states semantic-ui - `event.target` will be a `span` element if mouse or something else when using keyboard.

Comment: @TheWalrus I understand, but if you pass 'home' this: const prevState = this.state[name] gets this.state.home and then updates home: { ...previousHomeProperties, name: innerText } which replaces name and updates the state. Again, I only refactored what you had (assuming it is already working).

Comment: ok makes sense but this still isn't working..it's not updating "home"

Comment: Glad I could help out!

Answer (score 0):

In react semantic ui - https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-search-selection-two - it provides an `onChange` event

the options are to be passed in that format:

```
const values = [{ 
 key: 'AL', 
 value: 'AL', 
 text: 'Alabama' 
}, ...]

<Dropdown 
  placeholder='State' 
  options={values} 
  onChange={(event, data) => console.log(event, data)} />
```

so you should transform your state object to match and then you will get what you need back. The `onChange` will pass on the data object that looks like this:

```
{
  "placeholder": "State",
  "search": true,
  "selection": true,
  "options": [
    {
      "key": "AL",
      "value": "AL",
      "text": "Alabama"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "additionLabel": "Add ",
  "additionPosition": "top",
  "closeOnBlur": true,
  "deburr": false,
  "icon": "dropdown",
  "minCharacters": 1,
  "noResultsMessage": "No results found.",
  "openOnFocus": true,
  "searchInput": "text",
  "selectOnBlur": true,
  "selectOnNavigation": true,
  "value": "AL"
}
```

so data.value is what was selected, also - you're given the list of all the options so you can link it up.

> docs state they will pass on any relevant props in the data object

So, if you have:

```
<Drodown name="one" onChange={(e, {name, value}) => console.log(`${name} changed to ${value}`) />
<Drodown name="two" onChange={(e, {name, value}) => console.log(`${name} changed to ${value}`) />
```

you can easily now have a single handler that just changes your state as required, eg.

```
handleChange(event, {name, value}){
  this.setState({[name]: { name: value }})
}
```